# Is it possible to increase the number of shards in an arangodb collection as it grows?

Tags: arangodb

Since I am not sure how big my collection might grow in the future, I would like to know if I can add new shards when required. Is it possible to do this without dumping all the data and then recreating the collection with the new numofshards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharding is only available in arangodb clusters. You cannot reshard an existing collection with a single operation. You would have to create a new collection with desired new sharding and transfer all documents from the old one to the new. Very often folks decide to create the collection with the final number of shards on a smaller cluster and move the shards to new db servers as you grow.

Comment: What happens in case you know that your collection will grow but you don't know the exact final size? How can someone pre-decide the number of shards?

Comment: When your collection grows, your shards will grow. A growing collection by no means calls for more shards. Only when you end up with more db servers, than originally anticipated, to say compensate for higher traffic, is it that you need to have more shards per collection. In that case backup your database. Create collections with new number of shards, restore database.